# Data recovery after failed partition resize/move

Tags: data-recovery

I was doing a partition resize, assuming (yes..) that power loss was not a possibility.

Unfortunately someone turned off the PC during the resize operation.

As a result, many of the files are now corrupted.

Originally the drive was: 50 GB | 882 GB

I then resized to 50 GB | 832 GB | 50GB.

This was all fine, however I needed the space at the start of the partition.

As such, I tried using a tool to resize things, which was aiming for 50 GB | 50 GB | 832 GB and it was during this operation that the PC was turned off (without shutdown).

I have since tried:

1. R-Studio
2. GetDataBack
3. Find and Mount
4. EASEUS Data Recovery

Most of these tools show an inordinate amount of partitions, all with copies of the same set of files, but all file recoveries are corrupted. However, I have managed to get some files back through the "Extra Found Files" section of R-Studio. This leads me to believe that the MFT records or similar are corrupted, and the files are pieced across multiple partitions or similar?

However, I'm wondering, based on existing answers on here and found through Google, if I can use something like TestDisk to somehow fix up the operation and align everything correctly/fix the situation. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to use TestDisk correctly to resolve this situation.

If anyone has any advice at all, it is much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is probably one of the best tools for the task for expert users. And it is free.

If you still fail to retrieve the partitions, you can use [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) from the same author to retrive individual files.

Comment: I had to run through a series of recoveries with slightly different offsets for partitions (e.g. some files could be recovered with some offsets and not with others). All in all a pretty messy process but it seemed to recover just about everything.